# Complete newb - constant adb connection errors in Terminal

Tags: android, macos, adb

I am very very new to this so step by step help presented slowly and clearly would be fantastic! : Anyway, I've uninstalled and reinstalled my entire sdk multiple times, but I keep having the same issue.

I connect a device and open terminal. I run ./adb devices and get nothing. 
Unplugging and replugging in the device does nothing. I try to kill and restart the server and get that the daemon has been stopped and restarted.

From there it recognizes the device - hooray! ...UNTIL I unplug it and plug it back in and check ./adb devices again.

I am completely updated on my SDK and at a loss as to what the problem is.   It is killing me to run this every time I plug in a device, and even then, it will not always work.

---

> lgml--4:platform-tools srobinson$ ./adb devices
>
> > List of devices attached
>
> lgml--4:platform-tools srobinson$ ./adb kill-server
>
> lgml--4:platform-tools srobinson$ ./adb start-server
>
> - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
> - daemon started successfully *
>
> lgml--4:platform-tools srobinson$ ./adb devices
>
> > List of devices attached 
> >     5803f1e4   device
>
> lgml--4:platform-tools srobinson$ ./adb devices
>
> > adb server is out of date.  killing...
> >     * daemon started successfully *
>
> List of devices attached
>
> lgml--4:platform-tools srobinson$

---

Comment: I've never had this issue but am aware that you could be facing sdk compatibility issues. Yo might want to try making sure you are up to date and that you are running the correct sdk for your OS a your paths don;t look right for a linux/mac OS. Did you get your SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#ExistingIDE ?